# Histogram plots in pymc, what do different aspects mean?

Tags: statistics, histogram, pymc, confidence-interval, mcmc

I have defined a stochastic random variable (and  many more but for the sake of this question, one is enough)

`tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower = 0, upper = 74)`

After sampling using MCMC, when I plot the trace of `tau`, I get the following figure

[image]

Now my question is **What do this black line and the two dotted lines denote ?**

In all earlier figures that I had seen, the black line used to divide the area under histogram under 2 halves (almost) and dotted lines would also cover almost same are around the black line, so I used to think the bold line as mean value and the 2 dotted lines as 95% confidence interval (quite obviously I am wrong).

I will also like to verify my understanding about the height of the histogram.

According to me, **the height of the histogram at 45 denotes the number of times, the sampler picked up the value 45**, please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

The lines are the median (solid line) and the interquartile range (dotted lines). The histograms just illustrate the frequencies of the sample values.

Comment: under the section pymc.Matplot.plot() on http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter3_MCMC/IntroMCMC.ipynb

I have read that "The thickest vertical line represents the posterior mean, which is a good summary of posterior distribution. The interval between the two dashed vertical lines in each the posterior distributions represent the 95% credible interval".
Are median and posterior mean one and the same ?
At least in the figure above the region between dashed lines doesn't reflect 95% of the area

Comment: Its the posterior median, not the mean. They are the same only when the distribution is symmetric.

Comment: So, is it true even for the dotted lines? that the dotted lines will cover 95% area only when the distribution is symmetric (since here they don't and almost at all other places I have encountered them, they do and the distributions wee symmetric, although this is no reason)

Comment: No, the dotted lines represent the interquartile range (the 25% and 75% quantiles) of the posterior.